# Swift: WKwebview parsing multiple websites using for loop?

Tags: swift, wkwebview

So the idea behind my project is this. I have a text box that the user will type into and add to a list of "class codes". I will then use a for loop on these class codes and parse a specific website with that class code on that iteration.

On each iteration I would like to do some HTML parsing to scrap data, but every time i print out the HTML for that site, it comes out as an empty html document.

I would greatly appreciate some help on how I can parse an html website on each iteration of my for loop

```html
import UIKit
import WebKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var classCode: UITextField!
    
    
    var webview = WKWebView()
    var classCodes: Array<String> = Array()
    var sections: Array<Int> = Array()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
    
    @IBAction func add() {
        classCodes.append(classCode.text!)
        loadURL(code: classCode.text!)
        classCode.text = nil
        //might have to check if what they added was a valid course code, or else the parser might be trying to parse an invalid code
        
    }
    
    
    
    @IBAction func createTapped() {
        
        for code in classCodes {
        let url = URL(string:    "https://app.testudo.umd.edu/soc/search?courseId=\(code)&sectionId=&termId=201801&openSectionsOnly=true&_openSectionsOnly=on&creditCompare=&credits=&courseLevelFilter=ALL&instructor=&_facetoface=on&_blended=on&_online=on&courseStartCompare=&courseSartHour=&courseStartMin=&courseStartAM=&courseEndHour=&courseEndMin=&courseEndAM=&teachingCenter=ALL&_classDay1=on&_classDay2=on&_classDay3=on&_classDay4=on&_classDay5=on")!
            
            let request = URLRequest(url: url)
            webview.load(request)
            webview.evaluateJavaScript("document.documentElement.outerHTML.toString()", completionHandler: { (value, error) in
                print(value)
                
            })
        }
```

Comment: Do you even have to load it in webview. You can simply load the html from URLRequest and URLSession

Comment: you're right. I did that and I'm getting things to work now. Just starting out, so not sure what the hell i'm doing